# How do use LINQ with Entity framework to get a count of records on max of a joined column

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I am using EF CORE & MVC how can I select only the rows with the maximum column per group where the max(column) is in a joined table and I want result columns from more than one table?

Account = Table - record for each account. Members also have Accounts
 - Account 
 - SubscriptionPlan

AccountMembers = Table - record for each member of each account - just a look up
 - Account
 - Member

SubscriptionPlans = Table
 - PlanName
 - PeriodQty
 - NumberMonths

Scores = Table
 - ScoreId - primary key and identity
 - Version
 - Created Date

Members create scores. they are limited in how many the can create based on the PeriodQty in the preceding NumberMonths for any given account (eg - can only create 10 in the 3 months)
Members have an account of their own and may be a member of other Accounts

Required: to get the  Account, Plan Number of months, the count of scores created in the months for each account they are a member of.

```
SQL - relatively easy:
SELECT am.Account AS 'am account'
    , dateadd(month,-sp.NumberMonths,GETUTCDATE()) AS 'period start'
    ,sp.NumberMonths
    , COUNT(sc.ScoreID) AS 'Created'
    , sp.PeriodQty

    FROM AccountMembers am
    JOIN Accounts a
    ON am.Account = a.Account
    JOIN SubscriptionPlans sp
    ON a.SubscriptionPlan = sp.PlanName
    JOIN scores sc
    ON am.Account = sc.Account
    WHERE am.Member = 'jda@arundell.net'     
    AND sc.Created > DATEADD(MONTH,-sp.NumberMonths,GETUTCDATE())
    AND sc.Version = (SELECT MAX([Version]) FROM [Scores] sc2 WHERE sc2.[Company] = sc.[Company] AND sc2.[Account] = sc.[Account])
    GROUP BY am.Account, sp.NumberMonths, sp.PeriodQty
    ORDER BY am.Account

**LINQ ????? how do i do the** 
sc.Version = (SELECT MAX([Version]) FROM [Scores] sc2 WHERE sc2.[Company] = sc.[Company] AND sc2.[Account] = sc.[Account])

        LOA = (from am in _RdbContext.AccountMembers
               join ac in _RdbContext.Accounts
               on am.Account equals ac.Account
               join sp in _RdbContext.SubscriptionPlans
               on ac.SubscriptionPlan equals sp.PlanName
               join sc in _RdbContext.Scores
               on am.Account equals sc.Account
               where (am.Member == User && sc.Created > DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-sp.NumberMonths))
               orderby am.Account
               select new AccountCount { Account = am.Account, NumMonths = sp.NumberMonths, ScoreId = sc.ScoreId, Version = sc.Version }).ToList();
```

I could just suck up the whole list and do it in a c# foreach - but would prefer the DB to do it

Answer (score 0):

Didn't try to optimize your LINQ:

```
LOA = (from am in _RdbContext.AccountMembers
       join ac in _RdbContext.Accounts on am.Account equals ac.Account
       join sp in _RdbContext.SubscriptionPlans on ac.SubscriptionPlan equals sp.PlanName
       join sc in _RdbContext.Scores on am.Account equals sc.Account
       where (am.Member == User && sc.Created > DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-sp.NumberMonths)) &&
       sc.Version == (from sc2 in _RdbContext.Scores where sc2.Company == sc.Company && sc2.Account == sc.Account select sc2.Version).Max()
       orderby am.Account
       select new AccountCount { Account = am.Account, NumMonths = sp.NumberMonths, ScoreId = sc.ScoreId, Version = sc.Version }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much - after hours and hours the solution is so simple .Max()